# How to clip grid (based on points) leaving whole cells only using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am trying to clip a polygon grid based on a point layer as well as another polygon.

Basically I have a polygon grid and a layer of points that fall in the center of most of the cells. I want to keep only the grid cells that have a point within them. In addition, I have a county boundary polygon (partially shown in orange) that I want to use to further clip the grid, but I want to keep whole cells only. It's OK if the cells fall partially outside of the county boundary as I want to make sure I have full coverage of the entire county.

I am slightly familiar with ModelBuilder if that is the best way to go.

[image]

Comment: The question indicates 'polygon grid', so it looks to be a fishnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this I would:

1. Use **[Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000004000000)** on your points first
2. Use **[Select Layer By Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000)** using your "clipped points feature class" against your "grid feature class" and INTERSECT as the spatial relationship
3. Right-click on the "grid feature class" layer in the Table of Contents and **Export | Export Data**

Comment: If the point layer is clipped by the boundary polygon first, followed by the steps @PolyGeo outlines above, this should achieve a solution to the entire question.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I ended up doing it in reverse order from what Radar suggested, but the final result was the same.